# C++ WinAPI - How to get the installation path of an executable from its name

Tags: c++, winapi

Is there a way to get the installation path of an executable ( not self ) by using its name.
Say i want to find the path where a running process (eg : "notepad.exe") is installed on the hard drive from process list snapshot.

Best,

Comment: Not generally speaking possible. You can search the disk but there's nothing preventing the existence of many notepad.exes. (And in fact, on most Windows installs there are multiple `notepad.exe`s)

Comment: @BillyONeal notepad.exe was just an example. I mean in general. There should be a way to find the installation path of a running process.

Comment: Yes, in my comment `notepad.exe` was also just an example. In general, process names are not unique. You can have both copies of `notepad.exe` running at the same time, and then you don't know which one matches a given process given just the name. Same if you have multiple `foobar.exe`s or similar. You can even have `A\Foo.exe` and `B\Foo.exe` loaded into the *same process*.

Comment: @BillyONeal That is correct. I didn't think of it. Thank you for your information.

Comment: This sounds like a question, where you were given a specification for a feature, and you broke it into two problems: An easy problem, and an impossible problem. Now you're asking for help with the impossible problem. Please take the time to outline what you're **really** trying to achieve, and you may get better results.

Comment: @IInspectable first of all if i don't know something i have the right to ask. And there is not an impossible problem. As i know a running process should have a location on the hard drive right ? Then why it should be impossible to find it. Its okay for notepad but what about processes that can run only one instance. I asked is there a way to get the path or not. And you could have said no ! There is no need to down vote.

Comment: This is not at all what you have been asking for in your question. You explicitly asked for the *installation path*, not the fully qualified path to the module that started a given process. One of these questions is easily answerable, the other is impossible to answer. Please clarify your question to match your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The process list gives you the full path and filename of every running process. Simply enumerate the list looking at just the filename portion of each path, and when you find the filename you are interested in, simply truncate the filename off of the path and use the remaining folder path as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Either the process list snapshot contains that information, or not.

It is impossible to reconstruct that information after the fact.  Even if you also had a snapshot of the exact disk state matching the process list snapshot, there can be more than one file on disk with the same filename.

Get the executable path when listing processes, and store it in the snapshot.  Once the process exits, it is too late.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use the [`SearchPath()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score -2):

these functions should help

```
HMODULE WINAPI GetModuleHandle(
  _In_opt_  LPCTSTR lpModuleName
);
```

then

```
DWORD WINAPI GetModuleFileName(
  _In_opt_  HMODULE hModule,
  _Out_     LPTSTR lpFilename,
  _In_      DWORD nSize
);
```

Comment: The module he's looking for is not in his own process (question says "not self").  And because he talks about a snapshot, I think it may no longer even be running when he performs his analysis.